# Peak cpu and disk every 1 minute

Tags: magento2

I have been monitoring this problem for a few days and I believe that this increase in cpu and disk usage that occurs every 1 minute is related to PHP7 running the magento crontab.

Is this consumption normal or should I worry?

I looked for something strange in the logs in /var/log and found nothing

Follow how crontab is configured

### MAGENTO START

> - - - - - /usr/bin/php7.0 /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento cron:run 2>&1 | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >>> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
> - - - - - /usr/bin/php7.0 /var/www/html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
> - - - - - /usr/bin/php7.0 /var/www/html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log

### MAGENTO END

[image: CPU]
[image: Disk]

Comment: yes, Magento use much ram while run cron.

Comment: The attached graphics correspond to CPU and Disk